# Troubleshooting a crash on Unity Scene Load

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

After upgrading my project to the latest Unity version, the Android build crashes when changing scenes.

This only happens on the built Android app, not in the editor or when built for desktop.

Here are the crash logs from adb logcat:

```
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : Build fingerprint: 'oculus/vr_pacific/pacific:7.1.2/N2G48H/256880.5240.0:user/release-keys'
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : Revision: '0'
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : pid: 7232, tid: 7273, name: Thread-3  >>> gr.fourthedesign.VR <<<
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   :     r0 c7e074c0  r1 00000000  r2 00000545  r3 c5f8fdc8
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   :     r4 c5f8dbc0  r5 c5ac9ddc  r6 00000001  r7 c5f8dbc4
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   :     r8 00000001  r9 00000d1f  sl c0b83d30  fp c6635f30
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   :     ip 00000001  sp c557f700  lr ca7a01fc  pc ca793b18  cpsr 00001c69
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   :
04-24 12:14:01.875  7232  7273 E CRASH   : backtrace:
04-24 12:14:02.056  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #00  pc 00b29b18  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.056  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #01  pc 00b361f8  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #02  pc 0041f3d0  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #03  pc 0041fc3c  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #04  pc 00417d3c  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #05  pc 005c561c  /data/app/gr.fourthedesign.VR-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #06  pc 000478d3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 E CRASH   :      #07  pc 00019fe5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
04-24 12:14:02.057  7232  7273 F mono    : * Assertion: should not be reached at mini.c:2215
```

I have reverted the scene changing code to a basic

```
 public void LoadNext()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
```

that is called by a button click, but it has made no difference.

Any help in deciphering the crash log or a direction to look into would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering a similar problem, I ended up exporting all the scenes and importing them into a previous version of Unity.

It did not technically solve the problem, but it did allow me to finish the project.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with Oculus utilities.
If you have updated this there might be a problem with the android emulators using a disabled 32-bit display buffer (especially samsung devices)

Try enabling this and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, but where would I make the change? Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'm not using an emulator, I'm running directly on an Oculus Go

Comment: Build settings > player settings > use 32bit display buffer, worth a shot maybe.

Comment: Oh ok! Srry i wasn't to any help. Must be an error caused by either oculus utilities, fourthedesign + unity update. Do you have the the citrix driver installed?